# how to know if a USB device is plugged into the embedded Linux system

Tags: linux, usb

I'm new to the embedded Linux world. I'm using Nvidia Jetson Nano as my embedded SOC.
Now I need my application to do some specific thing, for example, show an icon, as long as a USB disk is plugged into the embedded board. How can I know if such a USB disk is plugged in?

I need to know the approach for knowing the as long as a USB disk is plugged in

Comment: Does OS on your device have udev? You can write udev rule or use libudev (or sd-device) to trigger your application on specific USB actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all USB devices that are plugged in with the commands :

```
$ lsusb
```

Or with the command :

```
$ ls /dev/ttyUSB
```

You could then check if one of the listed devices (/dev/ttyUSB0 for example) is in the list and do your action.

What programming language are you using for your application ? There must be libraries that can help you check easily if a USB is connected/disconnected

Comment: Hi Kupofty, I'm using C and C++ hybrid